# Image upload in a form affecting the post array

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that is to add a book to a database. When there is no image included in the form input, everything works perfectly, but when an image is included, an error message is produced, yet the data is still input to the database.

This is the webpage where the form is:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- first column with the title input then the image input -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" style="margin-bottom: 2vh; z-index:10;" class="list-features" name="title" placeholder="Type title here..." required>
                <input type="text" style="margin-bottom: 2vh; height: 6vh; font-size: 24px;" class="list-features" name="author" placeholder="Type author here..." >
                <div class="custom-column justify-content-center" style="height: 64vh;">
                    <!-- this creates a new button over the file input so that it can be styled -->
                    <div class="file-upload-container">
                        <label for="fileToUpload" class="file-upload-button">
                            <span class="file-upload-button-label">Select Image</span>
                        </label>
                        <input style="z-index:-5;" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="file-upload-input" onchange="previewImage()">
                        <br><br>
                        <!-- image preview -->
                        <img id="image-preview" src="">
                    </div>

                    <!-- script to preview the image -->
                    <script>
                        function previewImage() {
                            const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileToUpload');
                            const imagePreview = document.getElementById('image-preview');
                            const file = fileInput.files[0];
                            if (file) {
                                const reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.onload = function(e) {
                                    imagePreview.src = e.target.result;
                                };
                                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                            } else {
                                imagePreview.src = ''; // clear the image if no file is selected
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- second column with the description box then the price box -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="custom-column" style="height: 72vh;">
                <textarea type="text" name="description" placeholder="Type description here..." style="border: none; height: 100%; text-align: left" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="text" style="margin-top: 2vh;" class="list-features" name="price" placeholder="Type price here..." required>
        </div>

        <!-- third column with the category selection then the submit button -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="custom-column justify-content-center" style="height: 72vh;">
                <select class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" name="selectedLevel"  style="margin-bottom: 100px;">
                    <!-- php code to take levels from table and display as dropdown options -->
                    <option selected disabled>Select Level</option>
                    <?php
                    include_once("connection.php");
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT category FROM tblCategories WHERE categoryType = 0');
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

                    foreach ($results as $row): ?>
                        <option value="<?=$row["category"]?>"><?=$row["category"]?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>
                
                <select class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" name="selectedSubject"  style="margin-top: 100px;">
                    <!-- php code to take subjects from table and display as dropdown options -->
                    <option selected disabled>Select Category</option>
                    <?php
                    include_once("connection.php");
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT category FROM tblCategories WHERE categoryType = 1');
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

                    foreach ($results as $row): ?>
                        <option value="<?=$row["category"]?>"><?=$row["category"]?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <!-- submit button for the full form -->
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-list" name="submit" value="List" style="width:100%;">
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the code to process the data:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_POST = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $_POST);
include_once("connection.php");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

print_r($_SESSION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO 
  TblBooks (bookID, name, author, subject, level, description, image, price, sold, sellerID, buyerID, orderID)
  VALUES (null, :name, :author, :subject, :level, :description, null, :price, 0, :userID, null, null)");

  $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST["title"]);
  $stmt->bindParam(':author', $_POST["author"]);
  $stmt->bindParam(':subject', $_POST["selectedSubject"]);
  $stmt->bindParam(':level', $_POST["selectedLevel"]);
  $stmt->bindParam(':description', $_POST["description"]);
  $stmt->bindParam(':price', $_POST["price"]);
  $stmt->bindParam(':userID', $_SESSION['UserID']);
  $stmt->execute();

if (isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]) && $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] === 0) {
  // if an image was uploaded, specifies the filename for the image
  $filename = ($conn->lastInsertId());

  $target_dir = "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/bookshop/images/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . $filename . "." . strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  // check file size
  if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }

  // check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
  if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
  } else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      echo "The file " . htmlspecialchars($filename) . " has been uploaded.";
      header('Location: ' . $backURL);
    } else {
      echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
  }

  // tblBooks is updated to list the new file name
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tblBooks SET image=:imageName WHERE bookID=:bookID");
  $stmt->bindParam(':imageName', $filename);
  $stmt->bindParam(':bookID', $conn->lastInsertId());
  $stmt->execute();
  $conn=null;
}
?>
```

There is also an error that I'm aware of in how the file suffix is handled, but that is not relevant for now I believe.

When there is no image included in the form entry, the output is as expected:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Sample tite
    [author] => Sample author
    [description] => Sample descrition
    [price] => 8.50
    [selectedSubject] => Drama
    [submit] => List
)

Array ( [Email] => email@mail.com [backURL] => /bookshop/list.php )
```

But when an image is included, this error is produced:

```
Array
(
)

Array ( [Email] => email@mail.com [backURL] => /bookshop/list.php )
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bookshop/upload.php:23 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bookshop/upload.php(23): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bookshop/upload.php on line 23
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the $_POST array is empty. In case of that name field is null, which is not allowed in your DDL.

Comment: Not sure if `$_POST = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $_POST);` is a good idea.

Comment: You could try to not use `previewImage()` and see it that helps? Debugging by simplifying things. What clearly doesn't make sense in your question is that it looks like `$_POST` is empty, yet you say everything is entered into the database. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I've tried both removing that and other sections of the code and as long as there is an image sent through the form the issue still persists. Yes the fact that it's still being entered to the database is more confusing, [link to error]( https://imgur.com/a/Y9QOSKQ), [link to database]( https://imgur.com/a/wqhI0kz)

Comment: The issue might be related to the form's enctype attribute. When you use enctype="multipart/form-data", the form data is sent in a different format, which is necessary for file uploads but can sometimes cause issues with retrieving other form data. The error message you're seeing indicates that the 'name' column in your database cannot be null, but it's being passed a null value. This happens because the $_POST array is empty when you submit the form with an image included. The reason for this is likely due to the way you're handling the form submission.